# How to send/ receive data using a bluetooth connection for a real-time multiplayer game android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, multiplayer

I'm developing a 2D fighting game and I wanted to add a local multiplayer feature that uses a Bluetooth connection. I've searched the internet and all I have found is how to turn on the Bluetooth and how to connect to other devices but, I couldn't find how to send/receive data using a Bluetooth connection.
All I want to send is a value of an `int` for every frame.
So how can I use a Bluetooth connection to send/receive data?
Should I use a Bluetooth connection for this type of game or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Nice question. Congratulations. I favorited it to follow the developments.